# Read specific column in a excel CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, csv, model-view-controller

I have a CSV spreadsheet as shown below

[image]

I am trying to only read data from ColumnA. Read about cvsHelper but I don't know how to adapt it with my code below. At the moment the code read all the spreadsheet any suggestion please

C# code

```
 List<string> listmobilenumber = new List<string>();
 string filePath = string.Empty;
  if (attachmentcsv != null)
   {                      
     string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
      if (!Directory.Exists(path))
      {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
      }
      filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(attachmentcsv.FileName);
      string extension = Path.GetExtension(attachmentcsv.FileName);
      attachmentcsv.SaveAs(filePath);
      string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
      foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\r','\n'))
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
         {
           listmobilenumber.Add(row);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Instead of adding the entire `row` with `listmobilenumber.Add(row);`, use `split` again to split the row into columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse CSV files yourself use a library like [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). Be mindful that it's permitted in a CSV file for `Abc,Def,"Ghi,jkl",mno` to be present, i.e. the comma can be found inside values, not just separating values. Writing parsers is **hard**.

I've [written about CsvParser before](https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/csvhelper-a-tidy-package-for-working-with-csv-content), but here's an example tailored to your file structure, I've assumed that the names of your columns are *exactly* as given in the image. This replaced from the line `string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);` onwards:

```
IEnumerable<LineInMyCsvFile> allRecords = null;

using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    var csvParser = new CsvParser(reader);
    CsvReader r = new CsvReader(csvParser);
    allRecords = r.GetRecords<LineInMyCsvFile>().ToArray();
}
```

The code above reads the CSV file and puts the contents of each line into `allRecords`, you can then iterate over them and do whatever you want with them:

```
foreach(var record in allRecords)
{
    // Imagine you only care about the value in ColunmA:
    listmobilenumber.Add(record.ColunmA);
}
```

This is the struct that's used to map the columns in your CSV file so that `CsvHelper` can process it:

```
// I'm named badly, give me a sensible name that makes sense in context! :-)
struct LineInMyCsvFile
{
    public string ColunmA { get; set; }
    public string ColunmB { get; set; }
    public string ColunmC { get; set; }
    public string ColunmD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but somehow link to your article is dead.

Comment: @MihirDave, odd, it's working fine for me here - could you perhaps let me know what you're seeing so I can try and sort it? :)

Comment: this is what Google Chrome is saying "This site can’t be reached robertwray.co.uk is currently unreachable."

Comment: Please Don't bother, our office's firewall is blocking it, i was able to access it on my phone so figured. sorry to bother you

Comment: @Rob Thanks.  but I am having error on this line   using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath)) I changed the filePath to this  filePath =@"path + Path.GetFileName(attachmentcsv.FileName)"; as I saw on your blog but I still have the error

Comment: @Rob. I my code i forgot to mention the file uploaded

Comment: @EricAimeTchatchoua, you need to be more specific - what **exception** are you seeing when you run the code? Or is it that the code won't compile and you're seeing an **error** reported by Visual Studio?

Comment: @Rob When I uploaded the file from my computer and run the code I am having the exception  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\North_HCA_Texts.csv'.' > I don't want to force user to save file to a specific location that is why I don't want to hard code the filePath

Comment: @EricAimeTchatchoua, that's a completely separate/different question to "how do I get the data from the first column of a CSV file" so you should probably ask a new question for that. Noting that the path listed in the exception doesn't contain the word `Uploads` which you're attempting to add into the path, the fault likely lies there. Step through the code in the debugger and look at what's in `path` and `filepath` at each step to see where it's going wrong would be a starting point

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Rob I am just adding my final code  to help user with the same issue in the future

```
 if (attachmentcsv != null)
 {
  List<string> listmobilenumber = new List<string>();
  string filePath = string.Empty;
  string path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Uploads/");
  filePath = Path.Combine(path, attachmentcsv.FileName);

  IEnumerable<CsvFileModel> allRecords = null;
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

  using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
  {
    csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
    csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
    allRecords = csvReader.GetRecords<CsvFileModel>().ToArray();
   }
   foreach (var record in allRecords)
   {
     // Passed Mobile number into a list
     listmobilenumber.Add(record.MobileNumber);
   }
 }
```

CSV Class Design

```
 struct CsvFileModel
    {
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string EMPLOYEENUMBER { get; set; }
        public string JOBTITLEROLE { get; set; }
        public string BAND { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the row again in Add:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
{
    listmobilenumber.Add(row.Split(';').First());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first find "ColumnA" number

u can use some thing like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
{
   string[] tokens = row.Split(';');
   if(tokens.Length>=number)
      listmobilenumber.Add(tokens[number-1]);
}
```

Comment: Splitting on a semi-colon won't work for a CSV file! Also, it's entirely legal to have a comma inside a value in a CSV file if the value is quoted.